# Bessel K function upper bound $K_\nu(x) \leq \frac{1}{x^{\nu}}$

Tags: inequality, special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $x, \nu \geq 0$.

By WolframAlpha I found that
$$K_\nu(x) \leq \frac{1}{x^{\nu}}$$
is an upper bound. I want to know, can this upper bound be improved? Where can I find such properties?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your upper bound does not hold. If $x,\nu\geq 0$, it is true that:

$$ x^\nu K_\nu(x) \leq (2\nu-2)!! = 2^{\nu-1}\Gamma(\nu),$$

(equality is attained when $x\to 0^+$) and that bound can be probably improved by probabilistic techniques, by recalling that the Bessel K function arises as the PDF of a [product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-distribution).